# Is Visa D-Mult in Austria renewable? or possible to apply new one while I am inside Austria?

Tags: visa, schengen, austria

I am in Austria on a Visa D multiple entry, which expires next month. I am a Philippine passport holder, and was in Canada when I applied for the visa. I have not yet completed my German course and want to remain in the country to continue it.

Am I able to extend the Visa D while I'm here in Austria? Or do I have to  leave Austria and make an application from the Philippines? I just ask this since I am here already in Austria and I don't want to go back to my home country just to apply again for a new visa. It's not practical.

Comment: I don't know much about Austrian law but typically D-visas can be turned into a residence card when they expire. Is there any type of residence permit you would qualify for? That's what I would look into first. On what basis was the visa issued? For your German course? Again, I don't know about Austria specifically but note that student visas can come with a requirement that you make progress in your studies. Not attending/failing a course is usually not a good justification to get a renewal, quite the contrary.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible from within Austria. Quote from: https://www.bmeia.gv.at/reise-aufenthalt/einreise-und-aufenthalt-in-oesterreich/einreise-und-visum/visum-d/

> Bitte beachten Sie, dass eine Verlängerung eines Visums D in
>   Österreich nicht vorgesehen ist.

My translation:

> Please note that a D visa in not meant to be extended in Austria.